# How to split a list created through several iterations of a for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I am creating a list in a for loop in python but I have no idea how to separate results of each itertaion. For example I want to keep the even numbers from 0 to 10 two times and I want to separate the results. I tried the following code:

```
res=[]
for i in range (2):
    for j in range (10):
        if j%2==0:
            res.append(j)
```

But res is

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

And I want to have it as:

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

The point is that in reality results of my iteration have not the same length and I can not simply split my `res` based on the number of iteration. I do appreciate if anyone help me to do it.

Comment: append new empty sublist for every `i` before the inner loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a list in the first loop level which you then append to the res list to achieve that. Below is your code modified to minimum to achieve what you want.

```py
res=[]
for i in range (2):
    temp = []
    for j in range (10):
        if j%2==0:
            temp.append(j)
    res.append(temp)
```

alt. use a list comprehension. Note that the range function also has a third argument allowing you to set the step size, which if set to 2 removes the need to check `j%2 == 0`.

```py
[list(range(0,9,2)) for i in range(2)]
```

Both of these creates the list `[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
res=[[],[]]
for i in range (2):
    for j in range (10):
        if j%2==0:
            res[i].append(j)
```

Comment: This solution is only limited to a range = 2. Check @tbjorch's answer, which works for values > 2

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator for each up itrate:

```
def gen(x):
    for i in range(x):
        if i % 2 == 0 :
            yield i
```

Then:

```
array = []
for i in range(2):
     array.append(list(gen(10)))
```

Comment: the gen function it not necessary since range has the step size argument. This would achieve the same:
`array.append(list(range(0,9,2)))`

Comment: Yes, but i meant to mention a maybe new approach @tbjorch

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[i for i in range(0,10,2)]]*2
print(a)
[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```